# Multiple columns in MATCH AGAINST

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to get results from this query

```
SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(column1, column2) AGAINST ('text')
```

But I get this error `#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`

When I put only one column in MATCH it is working, two or more columns within MATCH doesn't work. I've seen people are doing it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The columns named inside `MATCH()` must be the same columns defined previously for a FULLTEXT index. That is, the set of columns must be the same in your index as in your call to `MATCH()`.

So to search two columns, you must define a FULLTEXT index on the same two columns, in the same order.

---

The following is okay:

```
ALTER TABLE tabl1 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (column1, column2);

SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(column1, column2) AGAINST ('text')
```

The following is wrong because the MATCH() references two columns but the index is defined for only one column.

```
ALTER TABLE tabl1 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (column1);

SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(column1, column2) AGAINST ('text')
```

The following is wrong because the MATCH() references two columns but the index is defined for three columns.

```
ALTER TABLE tabl1 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (column1, column2, column3);

SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(column1, column2) AGAINST ('text')
```

The following is wrong because the MATCH() references two columns but each index is defined for one column.

```
ALTER TABLE tabl1 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (column1);
ALTER TABLE tabl1 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (column2);

SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(column1, column2) AGAINST ('text')
```

The following is wrong because the MATCH() references two columns but in the wrong order:

```
ALTER TABLE tabl1 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (column1, column2);

SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(column2, column1) AGAINST ('text')
```

In summary, use of MATCH() must reference exactly the same columns, in the same order, as one fulltext index definition.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Victor, see examples above.

Comment: Excellent examples, thank you! In summary: your FULLTEXT index needs to match the columns you are MATCHing against