# MATCH AGAINST functions are not working with two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need fulltext search in two columns. The columns have fulltext indexes, but the problem is that the query works only with one parameter inside the MATCH function. With two columns, the query returns an empty result.

```
<?php

$s = "search keyword";

$query = "
    SELECT source,title,description,link,pubdate FROM feeds
    USE INDEX(PRIMARY)
    WHERE (MATCH(title,description) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
    LIMIT 40
";

$st = $cn->prepare($query);
$st->bind_param("s",$s);
$st->execute();
$result = $st->get_result();
```

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614230/multiple-columns-in-match-against helps or gives more info. Particularly 'So to search two columns, you must define a FULLTEXT index on the same two columns, in the same order.'

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for the comment. I already have defined FULLTEXT indexes for those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `compound FULLTEXT index` on both columns, not a separate FULLTEXT index on each column.

```
ALTER TABLE `feeds` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `i_title_description`(`title`, `description`);
```

Also your SELECT is missing quotes in `AGAINST`

```
SELECT * FROM feeds WHERE (MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE'))
```

Comment: Isn't this what I pointed OP at in my original comment?

Comment: I read only redevil reply that he already defined FULLTEXT on those columns and I assumed that your comment was for each column separately. Also, the quotes were missing.

Comment: So the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614326/1213708 doesn't explain that?